Kafka Log Dataset for model training
hi apparently this is my first post and I am very much a newbee into this field
I am trying to train a LSTM RNN model for log anomaly detection in Kafka issue logs an anyone help me with the dataset if available and if not what is the format I need the data in before preprocessing
have someone ready to get the data set ready and need to give him details of how I need the data

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
